# Do gases speed up as they leave the barrel of a gun? If so why?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, projectile, gas

I am attempting to understand the exact physics behind the recoil in guns. I made an original post on reddit [here](https://reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/vz53qo/why_do_gases_exiting_the_barrel_of_a_gun_cause/) specifically asking why gases *exiting* a barrel after the bullet leaves causes a sudden uptick in recoil compared as opposed to simply flowing out of the barrel and linearly slowing down (if you have a general answer on this it’d be much appreciated as well).

The answers I received said the uptick in recoil as the gases leave the barrel is due to the uptick in *momentum* that the gases experience as they leave the barrel. You can see in the comments I attempted to explain this to myself by saying along the lines of “the bullet blocks the expanding gases, so that when the bullet exits and stops blocking, the gases quickly rush out with an increased  speed quickly equalizing pressure with the atmosphere, and this increased velocity outward is the cause of momentum increase. Which is the cause of recoil increase, due to conservation of momentum.”

My issue is, why do would the gases actually speed up as the bullet leaves? The particles prior had a certain velocity, why would removing the blockage(bullet) cause a sudden increase in velocity at all? I understand that removing the blockage would cause a pressure differential inside the barrel vs out, and would cause the particles to leave the barrel, but why should they *rush* out? Think of it this way, if I was bouncing on the walls of a room, and then you remove a wall, I would indeed leave the room, but I don’t see why I should leave the room *faster*.

A similar question that might answer this one is : When we have a pressurized can of gas, the particles inside are bouncing off the walls at high speeds. If I were to puncture this can, would the particles gain speed rushing out of the can, or would they simply appear so when they’re simply continuing their original speed, but now have a place to exit and look like they’re rushing out?

Any answers to this are MUCH appreciated as this has been boggling me for a couple days now and I can’t find good resources.

Comment: Pressure differential causes flow. If a rocket just blew hot gasses at high speed out of the engine (out of their opening) without recoil we would not use them for transport.

Comment: Or, put a little differently, if the gunpowder were detonated in a sealed chamber, would there be any recoil ever?

Comment: That is a very good way to phrase it @JonCuster . To remove the complexities of the slide etc let’s assume the gun is simply a handle connected to a sealed chamber. Inside this sealed chamber there is a 2 part explosive attached to the right wall, next to our handle. Having the right part glued to the wall. I assume we would feel recoil as one part of the dynamite would shoot off to the left presumably, so conservation of momentum dictates the other part should shoot right, and that causes us to feel recoil as the dynamite glued to the wall pushes the wall right. I am unsure however.

Comment: I just realized the reason one would feel momentum in the scenario I described is because of the physical piece of dynamite. I’ve inadvertently added the “bullet” to the scenario, which defeats the purpose of my question as we care about how the gases affect recoil. So I suppose owing to your originally phrasing : if an explosion occurred in a sealed chamber, would we feel any recoil?

Comment: "!would the gases actually speed up as the bullet leaves" no they would not speed up but since the pressure inside is high there velocity is much  higher  than that of the air outside and they only can leave in the one direction , so the recoil is the same as for the bullet itself, only the mass is smaller. Just consider a volume of gas just as another bullet.

Comment: The bullet in a properly sized barrel is accelerating throughout the length of the barrel.  Which by definition means the expanding gas would 'like' to go faster, and the bullet's barrel friction and inertia are holding it back.  So yes, freed of the resistance of the bullet, the gas *does* want to go faster, but once it leaves the end of the barrel, it can then expand in 3 dimensions which dissipates a huge amount of energy. The gas moving down the barrel has mass, often about 1/4 of of the bullet's, so the acceleration of that gas down the barrel is a *significant* percentage of felt recoil.